# How do I access Win7 files through a Wubi 

Tags: 12.04, windows, wubi

After recently installing 12.04 through Wubi, Windows 7 is now not booting, not even in safe mode. There is one folder on the C drive that I need a copy of which I forgot to backup before installing Ubuntu, how do I access this through Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the partition on which you installed Wubi should be mounted at folder named /host (or it was, i am not using wubi since 9.10).

Answer (score 0):

Boot into live and run "sudo fdisk -l". Figure out which partition corresponds to your c drive, (must be something like /dev/sda2). Then mount that partition. "mount /dev/sda2 /mnt". Go to /mnt and you can get your files from there.