# Access Windows 7 Files from Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, software-center, ubuntu-netbook

I'm new to Ubuntu, so can any of you give me a guide of how I can access my windows 7 files from my Ubuntu 12. I installed it using Wubi. Looked around everywhere but failed.

Comment: Can you paste the output of "sudo fdisk -l"?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/113172/how-to-view-windows-files-on-a-wubi-install

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I access Win7 files through a Wubi ](http://askubuntu.com/questions/132163/how-do-i-access-win7-files-through-a-wubi)

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out, my windows was not partitioned, so after partitioning, everything was fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

In my case i just go to the Home Folder-->> File System-->> host-->> Users

Comment: Neither do I. :))

Answer (score 4):

Just open up terminal and write `sudo fdisk -l`. then try figuring out which partition is your c drive. and then just mount the partition as:

```
sudo mkdir /storage
sudo mount /dev/sda3 /storage //in case dev3 is your c drive.
```

Why not enable mount of the windows partition on boot time? There is a utility called ntfs-config which mounts your windows partition on boot time.
install it as `sudo apt-get install ntfs-config` and enable mount at boot as

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you installed Wubi on the partition where are the files you want to access, in should be mounted under /host directory.
If not, just launch the Disk Utility, find the wanted partition, and click the mount button. Partition should show up in Nautilus right now.