# How do I access windows folder from ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access Windows 7 Files from Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132168/access-windows-7-files-from-ubuntu-12-04)

I am using ubuntu 12.04 side by side with windows 7. I installed ubuntu in a drive which also contained windows folder. But  the drive is not shown in ubuntu! How do i access that folder?

Thank you.

Comment: is it a WUBI installation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is located in **/host** folder.

Go to the 'file system' then you will find **host** directory. It contains all the files of windows.

Comment: There I get it. /host fonder contained the folder I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can find [very detailed instructions here](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/auto-mount-windows-ntfs-partitions-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/). Alternatively, try these solutions:

1. solution. Install a program called ntfs-config, either from Ubuntu software centre, or by typing

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ntfs-config
   ```

   Run that program, select the disk to mount.
2. solution, using command line:

   First, find out what the ID of your NTFS disk is. Run this program from command line:

   ```
   sudo blkid
   ```

   That will a line for each partition, showing the volume UUID as well as the format. One of these should have the format "ntfs". This is your Windows partition. Now run

   ```
   udisks --mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/XXXXX
   ```

   where XXXXX is the UID of your Windows partition.
3. solution, mounting automatically at boot time: read [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113733/how-do-i-correctly-mount-a-ntfs-partition-in-etc-fstab).

Please, however, note that you cannot mount [hibernated Windows partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation).

Do not hesitate to come back if you have problems with any of these.