# New to Ubuntu. How do I access my files?

Tags: windows-8

My Laptop is running Windows 8 Pro (upgraded from Windows 7).

I decided I wanted to try a new OS so here I am.

I've installed Ubuntu using the WUBI.exe installer.

When I boot my laptop, I get given a choice of Windows 8 or Ubuntu. Cool, just what I wanted!

I want to try Ubuntu for a few weeks or so to see if I prefer it over Windows. But for now, I want to keep W8 so I decided to go for this dualboot/run alongside option.

Only thing is, my files. I have a lot of music, pictures, movies, tv shows and documents on my 500GB HDD which I make use of daily. But I cannot seem to find out how to access them in Ubuntu.

That's all I want ;)

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks for your time.

(I'm not a computer tech geek, I'm just an avid computer and internet user, I'm a noob at this sort of thing.)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, I think you will find this was answered in another thread here:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/132168/access-windows-7-files-from-ubuntu-12-04

Answer (score -1):

Step 1: Hit `ctrl+alt+T`
This will open a terminal window

Step 2: Type `sudo mount -a` and type your root(login) password.
This will mount all partitions on your 500GB HDD

Step 3: Go to file manager named FILES. Navigate to 'File System'.
You will see lots of directories(etc, bin, home, lib, dev, mnt...). Check the media directory for your partitions.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: On wubi you don't need to mount anything to access the Windows files, they're in the /host folder.

Comment: @UriHerrera Only the partition that contains the Wubi system will be mounted automatically in `/host`. Others will not. **Can:** However, **the method given here will not work**. `mount -a` only mounts partitions that are listed in `/etc/fstab` and, by default, additional NTFS partitions are not listed there. `mount -a` **does not** mount *all partitions* on all drives, only the ones configured in `fstab`. See [`man 8 mount`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/mount.8.html) and [`man 5 fstab`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/fstab.5.html) for details.